# What are the roles of celery-worker, celery-beat, message-broker?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery

Most tutorials on the celery/redis/rabitmq/etc are about the setup not the concept.

I'll describe what I know below, please fix me if I'm wrong or let me know a good tutorial page on the issue.

```
-> event happen (user did something and web server knows)
-> message goes to the message broker (redis/rabitmq)
-> message broker gives message to celery-worker for him to work
-> if he fails, he reports back to the broker, and broker deals with it

-> (periodic task) celery-beat says it's time to work
-> celery-beat gives the work to celery-worker (or through message broker?)
-> same as above
```